# Writing a PyCharm extension to display text beside source code

Tags: java, pycharm, intellij-plugin

I wrote an Eclipse PyDev plugin, and I'm trying to port it to PyCharm, but I can't find an easy way to display a text view next to the Python source code. Is there any way easier than copying the `PsiAwareTextEditorImpl` class and all its helpers?

I got the splitter control working so I can display something next to the Python source code. In this [prototype branch](https://github.com/donkirkby/live-py-plugin/tree/display-file/pycharm), I displayed a text editor next to the Python editor. Then I created a text file for each Python file to hold the display text, but that displays the text file's name, and it would be a pain to manage a bunch of temporary files.

I stepped through the standard editor class, `PsiAwareTextEditorImpl`, and found that it has a ton of helper classes, and eventually calls [`EditorPainter.paintTextWithEffects()`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/163.7743/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/openapi/editor/impl/view/EditorPainter.java#L325). Here are some of the things it does to paint text:

```
private void paintTextWithEffects(Graphics2D g, Rectangle clip, int startVisualLine, int endVisualLine) {
    final CharSequence text = myDocument.getImmutableCharSequence();
    // ...
    VisualLinesIterator visLinesIterator = new VisualLinesIterator(myEditor, startVisualLine);
    while (!visLinesIterator.atEnd()) {
        int visualLine = visLinesIterator.getVisualLine();
        if (visualLine > endVisualLine || visualLine >= lineCount) break;

        int y = visLinesIterator.getY();
        final boolean paintSoftWraps = paintAllSoftWraps ||
                myEditor.getCaretModel().getLogicalPosition().line == visLinesIterator.getStartLogicalLine();
        final int[] currentLogicalLine = new int[] {-1};

        paintLineFragments(g, clip, visLinesIterator, y + myView.getAscent(), new LineFragmentPainter() {
            @Override
            public void paintBeforeLineStart(Graphics2D g, TextAttributes attributes, int columnEnd, float xEnd, int y) {
                // ...
            }

            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics2D g, VisualLineFragmentsIterator.Fragment fragment, int start, int end,
                              TextAttributes attributes, float xStart, float xEnd, int y) {
                // ...
            }

            @Override
            public void paintAfterLineEnd(Graphics2D g, Rectangle clip, IterationState iterationState, int columnStart, float x, int y) {
                // ...
            }
        });
        visLinesIterator.advance();
    }
    ComplexTextFragment.flushDrawingCache(g);
}
```

That seems like a ton of work if I have to reproduce that, so is there some existing component that I can use to display a block of text that isn't coming from a file? Should I be creating my own instance of [`DocumentImpl`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/163.7743/platform/core-impl/src/com/intellij/openapi/editor/impl/DocumentImpl.java#L60) and somehow wiring that to an editor?

Here's what the Eclipse plugin looks like with the Python code on the left, and the text display on the right.

[image: Screenshot of Live Coding in Python]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create instance of LightVirtualFile, fill with any content and display in editor as file of existing type or your custom type.